# How to randomize background images in PHP?

Tags: php, css

I've followed [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/) but it doesn't work, here's my script:

```
<?php
        function ceklogin(){
            session_start();
            if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
                header("Location: login.php");
                exit;
            }}
        function css(){

          $bg = array('images/angel-beats1.jpg', 'images/angel-beats2.jpg', 'images/angel-beats3.jpg'); // array of filenames

          $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
          $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen

        echo '
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>OpenWrt Angel Beats Edition (v1.0)</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
             }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body> bla bla bla
        </body>
        </html>';
    ?>
```

Where did I go wrong? My images are in a folder called 'images' stackoverflow keeps telling me to add more details but I think that's all I can give.

Comment: You already have `images/` in the filenames so it turns out `images/images/filename.jpg`

Comment: When SO says to give more details - maybe tell us what's going wrong, what shows up on screen, or in your error log, etc.

Comment: Also: Show us some research effort - what did you google when researching this error, why were the results of googling unsatisfactory etc.

Comment: You've got quite a few syntax and structuring errors.  It'll require some work.

Answer (score 2):

```
shuffle($bg);
```

and then `echo $bg[0];`

You  are using complexed code for an easy job.

Comment: @hillz instead of: $bg = array('images/angel-beats1.jpg', 'images/angel-beats2.jpg', 'images/angel-beats3.jpg'); // array of filenames

          $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
          $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen

Answer (score 0):

You should not have php echo more php code. You should do this instead:

```
    echo '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>OpenWrt Angel Beats Edition (v1.0)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        background: url(images/';

    echo $selectedBg;
    echo ') no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
         }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> bla bla bla
    </body>
    </html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

@hillz try this code.

I think that you don't call the css function, and you missed the closing bracket of the function css in the declaration.

```
    <?php
        function ceklogin(){
            session_start();
            if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
                header("Location: login.php");
                exit;
            }
        }

        function css(){

          $bg = array('images/angel-beats1.jpg', 'images/angel-beats2.jpg', 'images/angel-beats3.jpg'); // array of filenames

          $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
          $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen

          return $selectedBg;
        } 

        $bgUrl = css(); 
?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>OpenWrt Angel Beats Edition (v1.0)</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            background: url("<?php echo $bgUrl; ?>") no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
             }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body> bla bla bla
        </body>
        </html>';
```